# Usar validacion html5 y enviar formulario por ajax

Tags: php, html5, ajax

Estoy intentando enviar un formulario que está dentro de un modal mediante ajax y utilizar las validaciones de html5, pero al hacer esto y dar click en el botón de enviar me redirecciona a la página a dónde envió los datos del formulario.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Agregar Cargo/Cuota</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form action="php/addEdoFinanciero.php" accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" name="from_addEdoFinanciero" id="from_addEdoFinanciero">
          <label>Fecha del Cargo/Cuota:</label>
          <input type="text" name="date_add" id="datepicker1" class="form-control" required >
          <label>Concepto:</label>
          <input type="text" name="concepto_add" id="concepto" class="form-control input-sm" required >
          <label>Monto:</label>
          <input type="number" name="monto_add" id="monto" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="100.00" required >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" id="new_EdoFinanciero" >Enviar</button> 
      </div>
      </form>       
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

este es el código de javascript

```
if (from_addEdoFinanciero.checkValidity()){
$(function(){
 $("#new_EdoFinanciero").click(function(){
    //event.preventDefault();// Aqui evitamos que el formulario haga el submit
    var frmData = new FormData($("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0]);/*elegimos el id del formulario y empieza desde la posicion 0*/
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "php/addEdoFinanciero.php",
           data: frmData, 
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,

            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){   
                    $('#modalNuevo').modal('hide');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                    $('#tabla').load('componentes/tablaEdoFinanciero.php');//FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA 
                    alertify.success("Datos Enviados");
                }else {
                    if (r==2) {//si hubo error en los datos
                        $("#modalErrores").modal("show");
                        alertify.error("Error en los datos");
                    } else{
                        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor");
                    }
                }
            }
         });//cierra ajax

    return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.
 });//cierra funcion de click
});//cierra function
}
```

Mi pregunta es si se puede evitar que me mande a addEdoFinanciero.php, ya intente cambiar por input type="submit" y ocupar el preventDefault pero ocurre lo mismo.
Este es el código de javascript que ya me funcionó para hacer lo que quiero, pero ahora después de dar click en enviar del formulario (se envian los datos y se quita el modal), si quiero volver a abrir el modal éste aparece y se quita de inmediato y se queda la pantalla oscura con la clase modal backdrop. ¿Alguna idea de porque?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#new_EdoFinanciero").click(function(){
    if($("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0].checkValidity()){
    //event.preventDefault();// Aqui evitamos que el formulario haga el submit
    var frmData = new FormData($("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0]);/*elegimos el id del formulario y empieza desde la posicion 0*/
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "php/addEdoFinanciero.php",
           data: frmData, // Adjuntar los campos del formulario enviado.
           contentType: false,
           processData: false,

            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){   
                    $('#modalNuevo').modal('hide');//cerramos el modal de nuevo 
                    //$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();//para quitar la sombra del modal
                    $('#tabla').load('componentes/tablaEdoFinanciero.php');//FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA 
                    alertify.success("Datos Enviados");
                }else {
                    if (r==2) {//si hubo error en los datos
                        //$("#modalErrores").modal("show");
                        alertify.error("Error en los datos");
                    } else{
                        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor");
                    }
                }
            }
         });//cierra ajax
       return false; // Evitar ejecutar el submit del formulario.+
    }
});//cierra funcion de click

});
```

Comment: Hola, creo que puedes resolverlo de forma simple, coloca tu boton `<button class="btn btn-primary" id="new_EdoFinanciero" >Enviar</button>` fuera del formulario (osea debajo de `</form>`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si mandas a traer primero tu checkValidity y dentro tu ajax, por alguna razón entra en conflicto el proceso y la ejecución del ajax no se termina de ejecutar, solo cambia el orden de las peticiones, primero manda a llamar tu evento click y dentro tu checkValidity, así funcionará

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#new_EdoFinanciero').click(function(){
    if($("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0].checkValidity()) {
        var frmData = new FormData($("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0]);/*elegimos el id del formulario y empieza desde la posicion 0*/
        event.preventDefault();// Aqui evitamos que el formulario haga el submit
        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "php/addEdoFinanciero.php",
               data: frmData, 
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,

                success:function(r){
                    if(r==1){   
                        $('#modalNuevo').modal('hide');
                        $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
                        $('#tabla').load('componentes/tablaEdoFinanciero.php');//FUNCION PARA CARGAR LA TABLA 
                        alertify.success("Datos Enviados");
                    }else {
                        if (r==2) {//si hubo error en los datos
                            $("#modalErrores").modal("show");
                            alertify.error("Error en los datos");
                        } else{
                            alertify.error("Fallo el servidor");
                        }
                    }
                }
             });//cierra ajax
    }else console.log("invalid form");
});
```

});

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Si se ejecuta el código de javascript (mande un alert), pero cambiando el código como me dices no sirven las validaciones de html. Ese es el problema que tengo, si quito el checkValidity no sirven las validaciones de html5 pero si funciona el ajax; en cambio si dejo el checkValidity si funcionan las validaciones de html5 pero se recarga la página aunque mande los datos por ajax y por lo tanto no me sirven los alertify.

Comment: Antes de llamar el ajax podrías poner en un try  el  $('#from_addEdoFinanciero')[0].checkValidity(), si todo sale bien se ejecuta el ajax, de lo contrario no dejas continuar tu scrip

Comment: Actualice el código, después  del evento click invoco el checkValidity(), prueba por favor

Comment: ya funcionó así, si manda los datos. Quite el de event porque no es tipo submit mi botón pero sirve igual. Ahora por alguna razón, despues de que doy click en enviar y querer volver a abrir el modal, se quita y se pone la pantalla oscura con la clase modal-backdrop, ¿Alguna idea porque?

Comment: Modifique mi publicación para mostrar como me quedo el código de javascript (el html se quedó igual)

Comment: Quedó casi como el último código que coloque, bueno entendí más algunos eventos y cómo utilizarlos. Éxito

Answer (score 0):

Prueba quitando el comentario al script

```
//event.preventDefault();
```

A

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Y eliminando en el HTML la acción del formulario

```
<form action="php/addEdoFinanciero.php" ...>
```

Por

```
<form  ...>
```

Comment: Me funcionó parcialmente, ya no me envía al php pero me recarga la página, entonces los alertify no funcionan

Comment: Ok, entonces elimina completamente el action del formulario

Comment: Me sigue recargando la página, quite el checkValidity y funciona bien el ajax (no recarga la pagina), pero al hacer esto no funcionan las validaciones de html5. No se si este utilizando mal el checkValidity

Comment: Usa $("#from_addEdoFinanciero")[0].checkValidity() como condicional dentro de la función $("#new_EdoFinanciero").click. Cuando valides, ahi si ejecutas el AJAX

Comment: edite mi publicación para mostrarte como pongo el código, pero sigue igual, recarga la página.

Comment: ya me funcionó como me dijiste, pero  ahora por alguna razón después de que doy click en enviar y querer volver a abrir el modal, se quita y se pone la pantalla oscura con la clase modal-backdrop, ¿Alguna idea porque?

Comment: Modifique mi publicación para mostrar como me quedo el código de javascript (el html se quedó igual)

Comment: $('#modalNuevo').modal('hide'); y $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); deben estar en .done(function( data ) { ...} del AJAX, además de reemplazar los datos cuando se termine de ejecutar el AJAX

Comment: sigue pasando lo mismo, si se quita el modal pero al volver a abrirlo se cierra solo de inmediato y se queda la pantalla oscura y no deja hacer nada hasta que recargo la página